# New to Oracle 11g Date function

Tags: oracle11g

I'm trying to convert a Sybase scripts into Oracle 11g. I'm not sure when it comes to translating the following and hoping someone would be able to help.

My Sybase has the following clause (simplified):
   SELECT * FROM MyTable1 a, MyTable2 b
   WHERE a.id = b.id
   AND a.date_modified > dateadd(dd, -4, getdate())

I translated into the following but not sure this is correct, please advice:
   SELECT * FROM MyTable1 a, MyTable2 b
   WHERE a.id = b.id
   AND a.dateAND a.date_modified > SYSDATE -4   ---> ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean it up, you have an additional WHERE clause that is not needed.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    MyTable1 a
INNER JOIN
    MyTable2 b 
ON (a.id = b.id)
WHERE
    a.date_modified > TRUNC(SYSDATE) -4
```